# Adding a API to WSO2 API Manager that has OAuth credentials

Tags: facebook, api, oauth, wso2, wso2-api-manager

We're trying to test out WSO2 API manager and having troubles adding some APIs. MailChimp was added easily because MC has not OAuth Credentials itself. But when trying to add Facebook or another API that has it's own API manager it doesn't work and constantly get a 401 Unauthorized. This is becaused both Facebook and WSO2 API Manager need OAuth tokens and obviously you can only send one Authorization header. Any help here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WSO2 ApiManager 1.0 still does not support (OAuth) secured back-end services out of the box. Hence it is not possible to register facebook, twitter apis via APIM.

Right now, an application is sending and authorization header to the APIM with a key issued by the APIM. Ideally if you send another authorization header, that will be forwarded to facebook api, but at the API Gateway level you need to remove the processed header which belongs to the APIM authorization.

Adding backend services with security will be added as a new feature to APIM future releases.

Regards,
/Nuwan

Answer (score 0):

Can you please explain why you want to use the API manager here? You can directly send your request to Facebook where the request is authorised.